# JSON Schema: multiple $ref get removed when reading file with require

Tags: javascript, jsonschema

I have a json schema defining several properties. I've moved 2 of the properties to definitions and I make references to them. I did this because I wanted to group them together and do some testing for these properties in a generic way. This works fine and all the json data is handled as before.

But, I noticed that when I read the json schema file into my javascript file, I only see the last $ref. I don't know what the cause of this is. I'd really need to know all of the properties that are referenced.

Here's an snippet of my json schema (in file schemas/schema1.json):

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
         "$ref": "#/definitions/groupedProperties/property1",
         "$ref": "#/definitions/groupedProperties/property2"
    },
    "definitions": {
        "groupedProperties": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "property1": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "property2": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I'm reading it into my js file like this (in file test.js):

```
var schemas = requireDir('./schemas')
for (var prop in schemas['schema1'].properties) {
    console.log(prop)
}
```

When I iterate over the properties in the schema from my js file, all I can see is one $ref. I imagine this is because it thinks the property name is '$ref' and there can be only unique names. Is there a certain way I need to require this file so that the first $ref doesn't get clobbered?

EDIT: My syntax wasn't passing the json schema validators, although I'm not sure why, so instead of struggling with that, I decided to do it a bit differently. All I wanted was a way to group certain properties, so I put the properties back in the main schema, and changed the definition to be just an enum of the property names comprising the group. So now my schema looks like:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "property1": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "property2": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "groupedProperties": {
            "enum": ["property1", "property2"]
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my js file:

```
var myGroup = (schema.definitions ? schema.definitions.groupedProperties : [])
console.log(myGroup.enum) // [ 'property1', 'property2' ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `require`, object keys are not unique (in that you may declare them several times in one object), but they are overwritable (in the same way that a variable declared twice is overwritable). You will only receive the last value declared on two keys with the same name.

I'd suggesting giving the refs a distinguishing ID, this will also aid  clarity when your code expands

Comment: I haven't found anything that said there could be other names for the $ref, I thought it was a keyword (without looking into it very much). I'm guessing from your answer that I could put any arbitrary name in there, like in a shell script. I'll have to try it out. I found another way to get what I wanted though. Thanks.

Comment: I tried out putting arbitrary names for the references and that works. I wonder why no one ever uses anything different in the examples online. Also, [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) works, but another did not.

Comment: what do you mean you "put in arbitrary names for the references?" I have attempted `$refOne: ./path/to/file and it does not work.`

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of problems with how you reference your definitions.

###JSON objects can not have duplicate properties
All properties in a JSON or JavaScript object are unique.  The second one will overwrite the first.  Consider the syntax for accessing a property to understand why.  When you read your JSON into a JavaScript object, you could try accessing the `$ref` property using `schema.properties['$ref']`.  If there were two, which one (or both) would you get?  JavaScript has no mechanism to distinguish because it is not allowed.

###`$ref` must stand alone
When `$ref` is used in an object, it must be the only property in that object.  All other properties will be ignored.  This is just one more reason why having two `$ref`s doesn't work.

> Any members other than "$ref" in a JSON Reference object SHALL be
> ignored.
>
> - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03#section-3

###`$ref` should not be used in `properties`
`$ref` should only be used to reference schemas.  In this case, the `properties` keyword is using `$ref` which is an object with schema values.  Using `$ref` in this way is not explicitly forbidden in the documentation for JSON Schema or JSON Reference, but it is not idiomatic JSON Schema and is consequently not supported by most validators.  Even if the validator you are using does support references like this, it should be avoid because it is never necessary and can make the schema confusing and difficult to maintain.

###Your JSON-Pointers are wrong
Your JSON-Pointers do not actually point to the schemas you have defined.  The correct pointer would be `#/definitions/groupedProperties/properties/property1`.

###Posible Solutions
This is what you were trying to do.

```
{
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
        "property1": { "$ref": "#/definitions/groupedProperties/properties/property1" },
        "property2": { "$ref": "#/definitions/groupedProperties/properties/property2" }
   },
   "definitions": {
       "groupedProperties": {
           "type": "object",
           "properties": {
               "property1": {
                   "type": "string"
               },
               "property2": {
                   "type": "string"
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Here is a cleaner way to include all of your `groupedProperties` at once.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/groupedProperties" }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "groupedProperties": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "property1": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "property2": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, since you are only using it for testing purposes, you can flip it around so the definition references the schema.  You can use the definition in your tests without it affecting your schema.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "property1": { "type": "string" },
        "property2": { "type": "string" }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "groupedProperties": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "property1": { "$ref": "#/properties/property1" },
                "property2": { "$ref": "#/properties/property2" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had down voted your answer because, while it has professional vibe in it I couldn't confirm any information regarding JSON Refs you're stating. JSONSchema doesn't define JSON References, it merely uses it. Neither [JSON Reference IETF draft](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03), nor [JSON Schema Definition](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html) holds statements such as "$ref" should be only attribute or can/can't exist in specific places only. If you have sources on the topic please include them - I'll change my vote.

Comment: I make two statements about `$ref`.  The first, "`$ref`must stand alone", is documented in the last sentence in this section: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03#section-3.

Comment: The second, "`$ref` should not be used in properties", is a statement of best practice and practicality rather than of specification violation. Using `$ref` for anything other than its intended (albeit undocumented) use of referencing a schema is non-idiomatic JSON Schema and most validators don't support it. In fact, I'm not aware of any that do. Although I agree that validators should fully implement `$ref` as specified, I still don't recommend using it for anything other than referencing a schema. It is never necessary and only serves to make schemas more difficult to read and maintain.

Comment: I hope that helps clear up your issues.  This answer does not deserve a down vote.  In fact, it is a much better answer than the accepted one.  The accepted answer was not wrong, but it was incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, even though I was checking multiple times I missed sentence. My issue with your answer was lack of referencing material while making strong claims than with the completeness of the answer itself. Feel free to edit the answer to include what you wrote in comments (it has to be edited so I can change vote). If you don't have time, I'll do so in couple of hours and then change my vote.

Comment: Reference and clarifications have been added.